# View project plan by week in a tabular format

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

There is a way to view your project plan in a table broken down by tasks ongoing in each week.  I cannot for the life of me remember how to do this, and I'm not having any luck searching.  Does anyone know how? MSProject 2013.  I think I did this in MSProject 2010 before.

As an example, it would say

```
Monday Feb 3, 2014   Task 1  Joe
Tuesday Feb 4, 2014  Task 2  Mary
Friday, Feb 7, 2014  Task 3  Bill

Monday Feb 10, 2014  Task 4  Joe
```

etc.

Comment: Do you mean the Resource Usage sheet, that shows tasks down the left and time spent on each by each resource weekly (or daily or whatever granularity you set)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are referring to some of the reports that were in 2010 that are no longer available in Project 2013.

However, you can certainly apply the Gantt chart view with any table you wish and then apply a custom group to group tasks by week.[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize reports were removed.  Is there a list of the reports that were taken out?

Comment: All of the reports that you could only print are gone.  The visual reports are still there and there are some very nice dashboard reports.

Comment: Ugh - this was one that you could only print.  OK thanks.

Comment: Most of the printed reports were really only views (tables) printed.  You still have the possibility of setting up views applying filters or groups I i noted above and printing the view either to paper or as PDF.